# Перебор элементов внутри датасета

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

У меня есть датасет, колонки с которыми я работаю это `chactnoe` и `DATE`, в общем составила такое условие, но оно останавливается после первого принта, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить это. Заранее благодарю

```py
print(len(chactnoe)) # 3163

def data(input):
  res = []
  res_small = []
  for i in range(1, len(input)):
    if i > 0.8:
      res.append(i)
      if len(res) > 10:
        print("check min_value")
        for j in range(len(res), len(res) + 9):
          res_small.append(j)
          if sum(res_small)/len(res_small) < 0.5:
            print("see you soon")

result = data(chactnoe)
```

Comment: 1) Код нужно приводить текстом, а не картинкой. 2) В коде происходит что-то непонятное. Вы вообще не используете данные из `input`, вы используете только их количество. `i` и `j` - это индексы `1`, `2` и т.д. Все проверки и вычисления вы делаете с индексами. Поэтому условие второго `if` никогда не выполняется, там всегда будет больше чем `10` результат, меньше `0.5` там никогда не будет. Потому что в тот массив копятся числа (индексы) начиная с `10` и выше.

Answer (score -1):

Смею только предположить что вам именно надо в этом коде, но вы не используйте входные данные вообще никак.

Допустим у нас имеется массив

```py
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Что бы пройтись по каждому элементу мы можем использовать `for`:

```py
for element in array:
  print(element, end=", ")
```

Что выведет нам `a, b, c,`

range же в свою очередь (если сильно упростить) генерирует массив `[start, start + 1, ..., end - 1]`.

Таким образом

```py
range(5) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
range(2, 4) == [2, 3]
# и т. д.
```

А это значит, что

```py
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
len(array) == 3 # длинна массива
range(len(array)) == range(3) == [0, 1, 2]
```

Таким образом:

```py
for i in range(len(array)): ...
```

эквивалентно

```py
for i in [0, 1, 2]: ...
```

Т. е. i будет принимать значения от `0` до `len(array)` (длинная массива)

А ещё `input` является ключевым словом и его бы заменить по хорошему... Например на `data`. А название метода тогда на `process_data`

А ещё вы ничего не возвращаете из своего метода.

Похоже вы хотели сделать что то типо такого:

```py
def process_data(data):
  res = []
  res_small = []

  for i in data:
    if i > 0.8:
      res.append(i)
      if len(res) > 10:
        print("check min_value")

        # Проходимся по последним 10 элементам res:
        for j in res[-10:]: 
          res_small.append(j)
          if sum(res_small)/len(res_small) < 0.5:
            print("see you soon")

  return res_small
```

А вообще хотелось бы услышать полную задачу, что бы я вам помог написать более красивый и понятный код

Comment: По-хорошему в Pandas редко вообще когда нужно по одному элементы перебирать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Это понятно, но
1) Я не шарю за Pandas
2) Без условия переводить бесполезно

Comment: В течении 5 минут вы можете отредактировать комментарий. И всегда можете удалить уже не актуальный комментарий. А так то да, без условия задачи можно только гадать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я сразу так и сделал) Просто вначале побоялся, что не будет пинга, а потом осознал, что в новом тоже пинга нет))

Comment: Суть задачи в двойном условии, вот мы получили res, к тором количество больше 10, а дальше перебрать следующие 10 значений, и проверить меньше ли они 0,5,если да, то вывести принт, если нет то идти дальше и опять условие if i > 0.8 проверять